# $X$ is a compact topological space, $f, g$ continuous. $f(x)\ge 0$, and $g(x)$ such that if $f(x)=0$, then $g(x)>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis

$X$ is a compact topological space, $f,g$ continuous. $f(x)\ge 0$, and $g(x)$ such that
if $f(x)=0$, then $g(x)>0$. Prove that there exists a constant $λ>0$ such that $λf(x)+g(x)>0$ for all $x \in X$.

I tried to rely on the Weirstrass theorem about the maximum and minumum of a continuous function on a compact. Then for $\lambda$ = max(f)*min(g)/(min(f))^2 everything is going to be right until min(f) is 0.

Afterwards I tried to build negation and work with it. But this also did not give me any results.

How to solve this problem? Or maybe I use a tools which are not useful?

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your questions: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

It makes reading them much easier.

Answer (score 1):

For any $\lambda > 0$, let $U_\lambda = \{ x \in X: \lambda f(x) + g(x) > 0\}$.

For a fixed $x \in X$, there exists $\lambda$ such that $x \in U_\lambda$: if $f(x) = 0$, then $\lambda = 1$ will do, and if $f(x) \neq 0$, then pick any positive $\lambda$ which is greater than $-g(x)/f(x)$.

Therefore, the $U_\lambda$ form an open cover of $X$ which must admit a finite subcover. Since $U_\lambda \subset U_{\lambda'}$ for $\lambda'< \lambda$, there must be some $\lambda $ such that $U_\lambda = X$, which is what you wanted to prove.

Comment: The number $(1-g(x))/f(x)$ may be negative. In that case $\lambda=1$ is fine.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc thanks! Editing the answer a bit.